# Spark Dataframe content can be printed out but (e.g.) not counted

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Strangely this doesnt work. Can someone explain the background? I want to understand why it doesnt take this.

The Inputfiles are parquet files spread across multiple folders. When I print the results, they are structured as I want to. When I use a dataframe.count() on the joined dataframe, the job will run forever. Can anyone help with the Details on that

```
 import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

        object TEST{

          def main(args: Array[String] )  {

            val appName = args(0)
            val threadMaster = args(1)
            val inputPathSent = args(2)
            val inputPathClicked = args(3)


            // pass spark configuration
            val conf = new SparkConf()
              .setMaster(threadMaster)
              .setAppName(appName)

            // Create a new spark context
            val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

            // Specify a SQL context and pass in the spark context we created
            val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)


            // Create two dataframes for sent and clicked files
            val dfSent = sqlContext.read.parquet(inputPathSent)
            val dfClicked = sqlContext.read.parquet(inputPathClicked)


            // Join them            
            val dfJoin = dfSent.join(dfClicked, dfSent.col("customer_id")
            ===dfClicked.col("customer_id") &&  dfSent.col("campaign_id")===
            dfClicked.col("campaign_id"), "left_outer")

            dfJoin.show(20) // perfectly shows the first 20 rows
            dfJoin.count() //Here we run into trouble and it runs forever
          }
    }
```

Comment: `count()` processes the whole dataframe, while `show()` is only restricted to the first `x` entries. Define, what you mean by "run forever"?  Minutes, hours, days? Any error messages you might have overseen?

Comment: The dataframe consists just of around 400k rows which resemble about 500mb of parquet files. I left it running for 6 hours and nothing happenend. It always goes immediatelly to step 198 or 199 of 200 when i open the job overview. No error message. I checked that. I am on this for days now and thought it could maybe be an indexing thing, or something wrong with the parquets. But why then the ok output and the option to filter...

Comment: Could you limit the input parquets to some fraction, to get a feeling of how long it takes? (e.g. time for 10k rows, time for 50k rows) And have you looked in to the logs, nothing unusual?

Comment: I will try that. Im new to Spark and the Log doesnt really talk to me. Can you give me a hint on what to look for. Thanks a lot so far, Martin.

Comment: Mainly watch out for dying executors because of OutOfMemory errors. I do not suspect any file-input to be faulty, as the output for at least 20 rows is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Use println(dfJoin.count()) 
You will be able to see the count in your screen.