# How to convert my dataframe into a list in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

THis code works perfectly fine in my older version

```
val allRecordsList = allRecordsDF.select("col1","col2","col3").collect.map(x => (x.getLong(0),x.get(1).toString,x.get(2).toString)).toList
```

But when I try it in spark2.2, I get 0 records. Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: and what does `allRecordsDF.count` show?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth, allRecordsDF.count actually shows 0! allRecordsDF.show() even displays the records. Counts does not seem to work. Please ignore the previous reply, i looked at the wrong variable. It is very confusing. The query works, and allRecordsDF.show() displays the records, but count shows 0?

Comment: @Srinivas: A comment on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216262/spark-dataframe-content-can-be-printed-out-but-e-g-not-counted) suggests that maybe some of the input data is faulty.

Comment: @Shaido, thanks for the suggestion. For some reason, when I do "order by" in the sql for that dataframe, the output is 0. I removed the order by and it works as expected.